# C# how to create a simple slide show of pictures in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, slideshow, transition

i wanted to be able to make a simple slideshow of pictures let say img1 > img2 > img3 and then just continually loop it in a pictureBox. is this possible?

i've searched the internet but i get lots of complicated example which i dont need. so its hard for me tom remove the unnecessary since im just a beginner in c#.

can anyone shed some light?

it would also be nice if i can do a fade in/fade out effect but i want to know how to do the slideshow first.

i did read a lot of people saying that it would be better using WPF but as i am a beginner,im afraid jumping to wpf would make it more complex for me. thus i hope i can stick to winform for now.

if anyone can give a code sample or any links to a good tutorial that would be appreciated.

Comment: All you need is a roll-over counter and a WinForms Timer.

Comment: You can refer to this article:
http://deepak-sharma.net/2012/11/29/how-to-retrieve-images-from-mysql-database-and-display-as-a-slide-show-in-windows-forms-application-using-c-sharp-and-vb-dotnet/

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is about as simple as it gets:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/vision.aspx